# How can I change the Windows 10 Colors settings from a WPF MSIX app (Desktop Bridge)?

Tags: wpf, uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge, msix

In Win 10 there's this part of customization settings

[image]

I would like to know if there's a way to change the Dark/Light setting and the accent color without having to change registry entries (which from what I see is a lot of overhead involving spawning other processes as desktop extensions and what-not and doing extra steps to publish the app after).

If there's no such way, is there a timeline to implementing these features? (for example having them under `Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current`) - (hoping someone from MSFT sees this)

Thanks.

Comment: How about your progress? Has your issue been solved?

Comment: No, I guess I got an answer that there's no way to do it nicely currently, but I didn't get any answer if there's a plan to implement it under the namespace that I mentioned (which is already part of the Contracts package, so a big part of that answer is redundant).

Comment: I have checked these properties and methods under the namespace you mentioned, there is no related API can do this, so maybe you need to change it manually through setting app.

Comment: No, I don't need to change it through the settings app, I can't tell the user "go change it through the settings app", part of the app is that I can change these settings for the user. And as I said, it can already be done through registry editing, but that's quite cumbersome. I guess you want me to mark your post as the answer. I can do that if you can also add info about the plans to have this implemented to be easily accessible (for example in the same way the wallpaper can easily be changed through `UserProfilePersonalizationSettings`, since that is part of  my question

Answer (score 0):

Currently, uwp hasn’t provide such api to change the Dark/Light setting and the accent color directly. Generally, it is recommended to do it through [launching the Windows Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app). Besides, if you want to use it in WPF MSIX app, you need to add the specified package reference, so that you could [call windows runtime api from this desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#earlier-versions-of-net-install-the-microsoftwindowssdkcontracts-nuget-package). Please refer to the following steps to do this.

1.Install the Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts NuGet package

- Click **Tools**->**NuGet Package Manager**-> **Package Manager
  Settings**-> Change Default package management format to
  PackageReference.
- Install the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts package`, note that you
  need to install the appropriate version. Please check the
  corresponding version below. (Installation details: Right click
  Reference-> Manage NuGet Packages->Browse->Search
  Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts->install)

  10.0.19041.xxxx: Choose this for Windows 10, version 2004, version 20H2
  10.0.18362.xxxx: Choose this for Windows 10, version 1903.
  10.0.17763.xxxx: Choose this for Windows 10, version 1809.
  10.0.17134.xxxx: Choose this for Windows 10, version 1803.

2.Launch settings app

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:colors"));
        }
```